# Почему не запускается приложение из .sh?

Tags: sh

Пробую запустить phpstorm из командной строки:

```
php /home/sergey/Apps/PhpStorm-182.4892.16/bin/phpstorm.sh
```

все корректно запускается.

Если эту строку положить в test.sh и запустить его, то - нет.

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
php /home/sergey/Apps/PhpStorm-182.4892.16/bin/phpstorm.sh
```

Почему?

Comment: А скрипт как запускаете? Через cron?

Comment: chmod +x ./test.sh сделали?

Comment: @PotroNik скрипт запускаю из php: shell_exec('/home/test.sh');

Comment: @balamutik да, все права имеются

Comment: А что выдает запуск скрипта из шелла?

Comment: В скрипте sh укажите абсолютный путь к php, это должно решить проблему

Comment: так это и есть абсолютный путь

Comment: @gubin, у вас php прям в корне лежит? Абсолютный путь начинается с `/`, например у меня на сервере командой `whereis php` я вижу что php находится тут `php: /usr/bin/php`

Comment: результат: php: /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php7.0 /usr/bin/php7.2 /usr/bin/php5.6 /usr/lib/php /etc/php /usr/share/php7.0-readline /usr/share/php5.6-common /usr/share/php7.2-opcache /usr/share/php7.2-xml /usr/share/php7.2-zip /usr/share/php7.0-json /usr/share/php7.2-curl /usr/share/php /usr/share/php7.0-xml

Comment: /usr/share/php7.2-readline /usr/share/php5.6-xml /usr/share/php7.2-mbstring /usr/share/php7.0-common /usr/share/php7.2-gd /usr/share/php7.2-bz2 /usr/share/php5.6-readline /usr/share/php7.2-json /usr/share/php7.0-opcache /usr/share/php7.2-mysql /usr/share/php5.6-json /usr/share/php5.6-opcache /usr/share/php7.2-common /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz

Comment: как найти свой?

Comment: Перепробовал все, ничего не помогает

Comment: если в файле test.sh пишу: #!/bin/bash
mkdir /home/scripts, то папка создается, а вот приложение не хочет запускаться

Comment: Добавьте в скрипт `/home/test.sh` после строки с `#!/bin/bash` строки 1 - `set -x` и 2 - `exec 2>/tmp/test.log` после произведите запуск и посмотрите что в /tmp/test.log

Comment: Файл test.log не создался вообще

Comment: http://joxi.ru/l2ZN9VjszBX1p2

Comment: папка scripts создалась